# How do I cannibalize people?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

[The BBFC](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:The_Smiling_Scum/Skyrim_Allows_You_to_Engage_in_Cannibalism) has confirmed the existence of cannibalism in Skyrim. I'm curious as to how this aspect fits into the game: Is it quest related like in Fallout 3? Where does the quest originate?

What are the pros (quest rewards, etc) and cons (reputation decrease, etc) of choosing to cannibalize?

Comment: Well, there was a quest I got for a Nord, and in the mine there was a cannibal in there sizing people up. You could kill him or let him live.

Comment: I'd start ate the feet and work up. That's just me though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll get the ability to eat any humanoid creature by completing a quest chain that results in acquiring the *Ring of Namira*.

> In Markath, you'll meet Kleppr and Frabbi, who will tell you a rumor about the Hall of the Dead. This sets up a quest chain that eventually leads to meeting Namira, who will give you a choice as to whether or not you should consume your first dead body.

If you do, she'll grant you the ring, and when wearing it, you'll gain the cannibalism ability.